# How to prevent edits from being rejected unreasonably?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently [suggested an edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/415720) to an answer where the poster made a simple and obvious typo which renders the answer incorrect. I also added some additional information on how to install the relevant program if it is missing on the user's system. The edit was rejected. I then submitted a [new edit suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/415734), this time restricted to just fixing the typo. Anyone with even basic knowledge of the subject matter would spot the typo immediately and agree with the correction.

However, the edit was rejected again by two people, neither of whom apparently even bothered to read the edit properly.

The first given reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.

On the contrary, my edit was intended to fix the answer in line with the original intent of the post's owner.

The second reason is even more silly:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
>   or is deliberately destructive.

Even if I had made a mistake with my edit, it's obvious that I wasn't deliberately defacing it or trying to promote a product or service.

This is a trend I noticed frequently on Stackoverflow, until I got full edit privileges on that site.

Is there any technique I can employ when suggesting edits, to increase the chances that reviewers will give it more care and attention?

Comment: What's wrong with writing your own answer? If you think the existing answer is wrong downvote it.

Comment: @RobertLongson There's a difference between an answer which is wrong because the poster doesn't understand the correct solution (in which case posting a new answer makes sense), and an answer where the poster knows and intended the correct answer, but messed it up accidentally with a typo, as in this case. Posting a duplicate answer makes no sense in the latter case, nor does downvoting an otherwise good answer.

Comment: @JBentley That wouldn't apply to the latter half of your first edit though.  *That* edit was very much correctly rejected for the reason listed.  To the change made just in the second edit, I'll just say that it doesn't seem like something that would be a typo, but it being outside of my area of expertise I would skip that edit.

Comment: Sadly this isn't a new problem. There are reviewers who reject edits that fix mistakes, on the mistaken belief that this is what they're supposed to do, despite the explicit guidance that edits to [“correct minor mistakes”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) are encouraged.